# Comparative form - which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, comparative

Which of the following comparative forms is correct?

> 1. It is much cheaper to train doctors, teachers, police and other vital
>      public service workers **than it is** to train astronauts or the
>      scientists and engineers who work on space exploration projects.
> 2. It is much cheaper to train doctors, teachers, police and other vital
>      public service workers **than** to train astronauts or the scientists and
>      engineers who work on space exploration projects.

Comment: They're both correct. NB: you might find our other site [ell.se] useful for future questions. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe both are correct. The second cannot mean anything different. It just uses fewer words. Not a contraction but a shorter sentence. This often happens in speaking where a meaning is understood and fewer words are preferred.